# OKTA different okta domain for different requests

Tags: okta, okta-api

I'm trying to use the okta api. I was able to use the api to create an authorization server and access policy with my okta domain.

The problem started when I tried adding a rule to the policy. When I tried adding a rule with my regular okta domain which looks like this: `dev-1345678.okta.com`, I got a 200 response but no rule was actually added to the policy. I then checked the request through the browser when adding one through the api and noticed that they're using a different okta domain which looks like this: `https://dev-1345678-admin.okta.com`. Only when I used that domain did I get a 201 request instead of 200, and the rule was actually created.

How do I know when I need to use the domain with the "admin" in the url and when not?

Comment: The -admin domain is only used for the admin console. You should remove -admin for your requests.

Comment: @MattRaible but that's what I said.. It works for all requests BESIDES a specific one which returned 200 but did nothing without the "-admin" and did work with it

Comment: It's probably best to send an email to developers@okta.com to create a support ticket. They'll know better than me.

Comment: If the URL starts with /api/v1, it's a public API and can be used with an API token, else it might be a private API which is internal to Okta. Can you share which API you are trying to use and the payload?